# Binary treatment with covariates

Tags: self-study, least-squares, proof, consistency

I am stuck on problem, asking me to show that in the model:

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1T + \Gamma X + u
$$

Where Y is the outcome, T is a treatment indicator and X are a set of controls (pre treatment). The $plim(\tilde\beta_1)$ shouldbe given by: $E(Y_1 - Y_0 | T = 1)$, assuming that: The expected value of Y prior to the treatment is the same regardless if people get treatment, and that there is effect homogeneity in the treatment group.

Specially I am stuck on how to write the estimator for $\tilde\beta_1$, because of the presence of the $X$. I know that if the $X$ where not in the model then the estimator is simply the difference in the means of Y.

Edit: If the $X$ where not in the model, then the estimator would be:

$$
\frac{n^{-1} \sum I[Y_i^T - Y_i^{bt}]}{n^{-1} \sum D_i}
$$

Where $I$ is an indicator for treatment, t is the outcome after treatment, and bt is from before the treatment. Essentially a difference in mean. But what does the estimator look like, when the $X$ included in the model?

Comment: Do you mean the maximum likelihood estimate for $\beta_1$?

Comment: @frelk no just plain OLS, no distribution assumptions

Answer (score 0):

The outcome under treatment $0$ is $Y_{0}$, which, conditional on $X$ is:

$Y_{0} = \beta_{0} + \Gamma X + u$.

The outcome under treatment $1$ is $Y_{1}$, which, conditional on $X$ is:

$Y_{1} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} + \Gamma X + u$.

You then assume that $Y_{i}^{t} = Y_{i,1}$ and $Y_{i}^{bt} = Y_{i,0}$.  So the estimator is exactly the same as the one without $X$, if $X$ stays the same before and after treatment (because $Y_{1} - Y_{0}$ does not depend on $X$ in that case).  Because $X$ is pre-treatment, $X$ does not depend on the treatment.

Comment: and then compute the difference in expected value conditional on treatment and no treatment?

Comment: Right.  $E\left[Y_{i}^{t} - Y_{i}^{bt} | T_{i} = 1\right] = E\left[Y_{i,1} - Y_{i,0} | T = 1\right]$.  (if $Y_{i,1}$ is the outcome of subject $i$ when they get the treatment and $Y_{i,0}$ is the outcome of subject $i$ when they do not).  You're assuming there is no selection here so $E\left[u_{i} | T=1\right] = E\left[u_{i} | T = 0\right]$.  That's what makes this work as an estimator.

Comment: Hmm ok that makes sense. For my sake, how is assuming a fixed $\hat \beta_1$ different from assuming $E(Y_{i,1} - Y_{i,0}|X, t = 1) = E(Y_{i,1} - Y_{i,0}|t = 1)$ (an assumption made in the book I am reading)?